# Тире в предложении «Это настоящее искусство»

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Многие ставят тире после "это": **Это — настоящее искусство.**
Я же считаю, что ставить тире не нужно. Я прав?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оба варианта возможны.

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92

7. При подлежащем, выраженном словом ***это***, между главными членами предложения тире ставится в зависимости **от логического выделения подлежащего и наличия паузы после него;** ср.: Это — начало всех начал. — Это неплохое начало; Это — одиночество (Ч.).

Примеры:

*Маргарита, спасибо за подборку! **Это** настоЯщее искусство! Прекрасный художник, талантище!*  Обсуждение статьи (2016)]

*В графике Эйзенштейна есть и законченность композиции, и незапечатленное мгновение ― предвестие перемены. **Это** настоящее откровЕние.*  [Александр Сокуров. Руки (2007)].

*Переводчик рассказал, что село это столетиями славится шитьем и вышивками по сукну, по коже, что **Это** ― настоЯщее искусство*.  [Татьяна Окуневская. Татьянин день (1998)]

― *Папа, ну а **Это** ― настоЯщее приключение? ― ликуя, спросил Серёжа.* [И. Грекова. Знакомые люди (1982)]